# Неоднозначность getBoundingClientRect() JS

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся с неоднозначностью *getBoundingClientRect()*.
А именно: есть `div` c id `c1` в коде `console.log(c1.getBoundingClientRect().x);` в консоль выводит **244**, но в консоли если ввести `c1.getBoundingClientRect().x` выведет **122**, правильное значение консольное. В чем тут дело?

[image: отступ от края окна]

[image: alert(c1.getBoundingClientRect().x);]

[image: консоль]

```js
console.log(c1.getBoundingClientRect().x)
```

```css
.sector{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:row;  
  min-width: 100px;
}
.spring{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: calc((100vw - 100vh) / 2);
  background-color: green;
}
.q1{
  background-color: blue;
}
.content{
  min-width: 30px;
  max-width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: yellow;
}
#c1{
  height:30px;
  width:30px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
 <div class="sector">
<div class="spring"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div id="c1"></div>
  </div>
<div class="spring q1"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67179/discussion-on-question-by-jarry-roxwell--getboundingclientrect).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что когда ты открываешь консоль, размер окна изменятся и элемент сдвигается. Поэтому с закрытой консолью значение 244, а с открытой - 122.

> Вынес `<script>` за `<body>` и везде стало 122

Значит были стили, которые подключались после скрипта, либо назначались этому элементу другим скриптом. Соответственно на момент первого вычисления они ещё не были применены, а при проверки руками из консоли - уже были.

Comment: Ну и за что минус?

Comment: консоль тут не причем

Comment: она в отдельном открыта

Comment: @JarryRoxwell, тогда добавь в вопрос сниппет, на котором можно было бы увидеть описанное в вопросе поведение.

Comment: только что проверил, хотя знал что такого не должно быть, Jarry Roxwell прав, консоль тут не причем

Comment: @Qwertiy, там все нормально показывает, сейчас вообще ее закрыл и выкинул значение алертом, тоже самое

Comment: @Air, ну хоть кто-нибудь может показать код, на котором проверяет? Или только минусы ставить все могут? Сейчас вот вообще возьму и закрою вопрос с требованием добавить пример. И ответ удалю.

Comment: @Qwertiy скринами могу, на jsfiddle все нормально работает

Comment: @JarryRoxwell, вообще-то нужен код, а не скрины. Но можешь для начала и скрины скинуть.

Comment: @Qwertiy, он же определяет положение от левого края экрана, пр чем тут ширина окна? какая разница ширина или я что-то не понимаю?

Comment: @Air, из-за ширины окна может по-другому перенестись текст и элемент подвинется. А ещё могут быть media-запросы в css, из-за которых тоже что-то подвинется. Уменьшение ровно в 2 раза очень похоже на уменьшение отступов для более узких экранов.

Comment: @Qwertiy  я про медиа и подумал, когда предложил ему открыть консоль в отдельном окне, но и там не разницы

Comment: @Air media-запросов нет

Comment: ну вот я тебе уже сказал, лучше добвь код, виднее будет

Comment: @Qwertiy, раз тут все решилось, посмотри  мой последний вопрос, можешь в нем помочь? прислать ссылку или сам заглянешь?

Comment: @JarryRoxwell, прими вопрос... Я думаю будет справедливо

Comment: @Air забыл про галочку